# Вывод уникальных записей из базы данных

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, mysqli, фильтр

Есть фильтр, в нём поле "Район", нужно вывести в список этого поля все районы, которые есть в БД, но так, чтобы они не повторялись.

Например: у нас есть 5 записей. У первого поле "район" - 1, у второго - 2, у третьего - 2, у четвёртого - 2 и у пятого - 7.
В фильтре список должен быть таким: Район{1,2,7}

Не могу понять, как не выводить повторяющиеся поля. В php начинающий, мало функций знаю, поэтому не ругайте.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два способа получить уникальные значения из таблицы, первый заключается в указании ключевого слова `DISTINCT` около извлекаемого поля

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT distinct_id
FROM
  tbl;
```

Второй, заключается в группировке по полю `distinct_id` при помощи ключевого слова `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT
  distinct_id
FROM
  tbl
GROUP BY
  distinct_id;
```

В обоих случаях вы получаете выборку только уникальных значений поля `distinct_id`.

Comment: А для чего второй способ?

Comment: @D-side Вообще он крайне удобный, хотя некоторые SQL-пуристы считают, что не стоит применять GROUP BY только для получения уникальных значений, так как группы фактически не используются. Хотя мне GROUP BY кажется более читабельным и логичным, чем DISTINCT, который еще и не каждый вспомнит.